# FileProvider Showing blank in android Nougat

Tags: android, pdf

I have a pdf file in device's internal storage with location as "/storage/emulated/0/MyPdf/test.pdf". While accessing it with FileProvider, pdf reader is blank filled with black colour.
 path_file is as follows

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>`

java code snippet in my code is

```
File pdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyPdf/" + "test.pdf"); 
    Uri path  = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(),"com.test.pdf.fileprovider", pdfFile);
    Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
    pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    try{
        startActivity(pdfIntent);
    }catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No Application available to view PDF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

provider in My manifest file

```
 <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.test.pdf.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

Please help me to overcome this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

with:

```
pdfIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

as you should not need `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`, but you *definitely* need `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION`.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the second argument for .getUriForFile() must be authorities you have mentioned in manifest file?

```
"com.test.pdf.fileprovider" instead of ""com.visakh.horizon.horizon.fileprovider"
```

Comment: sorry, its a mistake happened while copying the code. Its same in both .Now I changed it in the question